# Movie where three college friends build a device that sends microwave signals to space to take pictures

Tags: story-identification, movie

Three college friends build a device from computer parts at school. They create a device that sends microwave signals to space to take pictures. The three guys are excited and kept going further and further out. The government noticed and said they made contact and the shadow beings came into our dimension taking the computer and him. What's the movies name?

Comment: Can you tell us when you saw this movie? Was it old when you saw it. Was it English language? Where and when was it set? Add _any_ detail you can remember, no matter how small, funny hairstyles, character names or appearance, the actors, setting etc

Answer (score 7):

Is this ***[Shadows on the Wall](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2601260/)*** (2015), also known as *Cosmic Contact*...?

> Three college students try to create a device capable of reaching beyond the boundaries of the known universe. Unfortunately for them, they succeed...

This is a low budget film with a similar look to *Primer* (2004).

The plot involves three college students who cobble together a device that allows them to view images of deep space using background radiation.

> [image: Image of the protagonists from "Shadows on the Wall" (2015).]
>
> <sub>*Shadows on the Wall* (2015)</sub>

They keep looking further and further out, until they finally push past the edge of the observable universe, but in doing so, their device becomes a beacon to shadowy aliens that exist on another plane of reality.

> [image: Image of shadowy aliens from "Shadows on the Wall" (2015).]
>
> <sub>*Shadows on the Wall* (2015)</sub>

The students also draw the attention of *Men in Black*-style government agents who aren't too pleased with what they've been doing.

> [image: Image of government agents from "Shadows on the Wall" (2015).]
>
> <sub>*Shadows on the Wall* (2015)</sub>

In the end, the aliens take away the device and one of the students.